# Spring & JSP: Get value from certain input using spring controller

Tags: spring, jsp

Can somebody help me to get value from certain input using spring controller.

**I have 2 input data, and I just need a value from one of these inputs:**

```
<input type="text" name="data01" />
<input type="text" name="data02" />
```

I just want to retrieve a value from "data01".

**I just have used**

```
(HttpServletRequest) request.getParameter("data01")
```

**Or**

```
@RequestParam(value="data01") Integer data01
```

**but the value is null.**

Can somebody help me

EDIT:
jsp:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <input type="text" name="data01" />
      <input type="text" name="data02" />
   </tr>
</table>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAllData(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String retrievedData = request.getParameter("data01");
    System.out.println("data= " + retrievedData);

    model.addAttribute("data", new data());

    return "data";

}
```

The retrievedData value is null.

Comment: can you post your html form. and the controller method.

Comment: can u debug my updated post, is there anything wrong? @Kerppag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the parameter using this method

```
<form action="/user" method="get">
  <table>
     <tr>
        <input type="text" name="data01" />
        <input type="text" name="data02" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
     </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

and in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAllData(String data01, ModelMap model) {
   // your logic here
}
```

and from the code you have posted. You are casting the parameter to `HttpServletRequest`

```
request.getParameter("data01") //returns String as default.
Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("data01");
```

From your comment at @user1516735 answer, you  cannot use it outside of the form tag. Unless you include it in the parameter from ajax or append the value of "name01" in the url as `/user?name01=value`

Comment: do I need a button? because with your code I still don't get the value of data01

Comment: In submitting form. You should always have a submit button or any ajax function that will do the submitting of the form. I suggest your read about HTML forms

Comment: thanks a lot, I have solved this problem. Just add a button to send the data. Sorry for my newbie question, because daily I just concern in the backend process.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the value of data01 by using the below code:

```
request.getParameter("data01");
```

Here request is of type HttpServletRequest. Make sure your input control is inside **form** tag.

Comment: I just followed your suggestion, and the result is still null.

Comment: @thebe.alfarisi we need to have it inside form tag